# I am trying to sum up values in a csv file using python and it is returning Zero, anyone with an idea

Tags: python

```py
import csv

with open('/Users/a/Documents/student_data.csv', 'r') as data:
    student_csv = csv.reader(data)
    next(data)
    for a in student_csv:
        sum_gpa = 0
        student_num = 0
        sum_gpa += float(a[2])
        student_num += 1
        avr_gpa = sum_gpa / student_num
        print(avr_gpa)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include sample input.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong and you're resetting the statistics every row:

```
import csv

with open('/Users/a/Documents/student_data.csv', 'r') as data:
    student_csv = csv.reader(data)
    next(data)
    sum_gpa = 0
    student_num = 0
    for a in student_csv:
        sum_gpa += float(a[2])
        student_num += 1
    avr_gpa = sum_gpa / student_num
    print(avr_gpa)
```